# Origin of よろしく's other meanings

Tags: grammar, etymology, expressions, suffixes

The other meanings I'm referring to are from noun + よろしく (as if) and よろしく ... べし (by all means). I wonder why it also lacks some meanings from よく, as よろしい is the respectful form of よい, I think. I think it may be because of the respect that よろしく has in comparison to よく. (I saw other posts on よろしく but didn't see it's origin)

Comment: Can you elaborate your question? Do you understand よろし and よし are different words? よろしく does not contain よく.

Comment: What, I thought that 宜しい was a respectful form of よい/よし I don't think that makes my question any less valid, does it?

Comment: I searched よろし up and saw that it has a less high evaluation in comparison to よし... I wonder if よろしく...べし comes from meaning 4 of よく on goo dictionary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Old Japanese, [よし](https://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%82%88%E3%81%97) meant "excellent", but [よろし](https://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%82%88%E3%82%8D%E3%81%97)  was a different adjective that had mixed connotations like "satisfactory", "not bad", "so-so", "mundane", "appropriate", etc. So よろしくお願いします is a modest request for a treatment that is fair enough; it's not a word that asks for excellency.

Likewise, ～よろしく as a suffix has a connotation like "not perfect but good enough to be passable as ～". I couldn't find any explanation regarding how and when よろしく started to work as a suffix, but considering that よろし was sometimes used in a sarcastic or negative manner, it doesn't seem surprising.

よろしく meaning "by all means" seems to be a [*kanbun kundoku*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanbun) tradition. I have never seen this sense appear in normal Japanese sentences, including classical ones.

Comment: I feel bummed out now that I found out that there's to clear explanation as to why よろしく as a suffix can mean an ironic as if

Comment: I'm still confused on よろしく... べし. I think よろしい is like いい加減 and then べし is setting a standard.  Actually the answer was that not excellent but not passable was the sense that the suffix よろしく meaning ように came from

Comment: @StarPeep It is usually used sarcastically, but not always. As for "by all means", the *kanbun kundoku* tradition means that it may be related to the Chinese use of the kanji 宜 (which I know nothing about) but has little to do with the history of the Japanese adjective よろし.